# google maps polyline mouseout event

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have polyline different colors.
I get colors from mysql db.. Everything working, but:
mouseout function is not returning same color.. it shows only default(red) color of line..

Comp is completed percent.default color is red.

could I explain?

P.S. Sorry for my English..

```
function pinfo(poly, html) {


      google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mouseover",function(){ poly.setOptions({
 strokeColor:'#FFFFFF', strokeOpacity: .8});});

      google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mouseout",function(){ 
poly.setOptions({strokeColor:colorr});});


     google.maps.event.addListener(poly,'click', function(event) {
    mpenc.setContent(html);
    mpenc.setPosition(event.latLng);
    mpenc.open(map);
  });

}      

  if (comp < 1) { 
 colorr = '#FA0505' }

 if (comp > 0 && comp < 25 ) { 
 colorr = '#FFA640' }

 if (comp > 24 && comp < 50) { 
 colorr = '#FFFD91' }

 if (comp > 49 && comp < 75) { 
 colorr = '#E8E400' }

 if (comp > 74 && comp < 100) { 
 colorr = '#BFFFAD' }

 if (comp == 100) { 
 colorr = '#0F8500' }
        var poly = new g.Polyline({
                          map:map,
                          path:pts,
                          strokeColor:colorr,
                          strokeWeight:en,
                          clickable: true,

                          });

pinfo(poly,html);
```

Comment: We don't have your complete code so it's hard to tell. The way you are declaring the `setOptions` seems correct. Are you sure the `colorr` variable is available within the `pinfo` function?

Comment: Also please indent your code correctly when posting here. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you.. It`s answer not a comment .. I forgot to declare `colorr` ..

Comment: I will add this as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that the `colorr` variable is available in your `pinfo` function.

For example:

```
var colorr;

function pinfo(poly, html) {

    // Use the colorr variable here
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: thank you bro! i`v use that `function pinfo(poly, html,colorr) {}`